# Blue Prism - Internal : AMI error occurred in WaitStart Stage 'Wait4' on page 'Navigate menu' - Not Connected

Tags: blueprism

I'm getting this error message 
"Internal : AMI error occurred in WaitStart Stage 'Wait4' on page 'Navigate menu' - Not Connected" in relation to trying to perform the Blueprism sample project. (still a rookie, so please be gentle)

I have included an "attached action" on the business object page. The weird thing is when the process is ran only through Object it works fine. But when I try to connect the different actions in the process studio the error occurs after a couple of actions.

1. Launch works fine
2. Log-in works fine
3. Navigate (finding that menu seems not to work) When I spy nothing seems to be wrong.

So dear experts - where do I fail?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRbaO.png)

Comment: Oh yes, and if I launch the application modeller, launch the object and then run it, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it fails for you is because you have the decision arrows switched. You should attach if you are *not* connected.

Comment: Thanks for that comment. However, it did not change anything regarding to the problem with AMI. I am still getting the same erro

Answer (score 0):

In the Wait Stage, Probably you are looking for an Element as Check Exists. Change it to Parent Document Loaded. It should work fine. Thank you